# Try to patch TEXT in a Classroom announcements over API

Tags: api, http-status-code-404, patch, google-classroom

I'm not able to change 'text' in an announcements using Google-Classroom API.

When I try to use the PATCH method I have the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "updateMask: Non-supported update mask fields specified",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "updateMask",
            "description": "Non-supported update mask fields specified"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[request and updateMask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKEOd.png)

I send a `updateMask` 'text' and a text in request body.

When I try with the `updateMask` 'state,scheduledTime' I get a successful.
Has anyone ever had this error?

References:
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/patch

Comment: Can you show how you wrote your request payload body?

Comment: I'm using the API Explorer from https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/patch, I can't see the payload body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue.  Despite what the documentation seems to indicate (that updateMask can be text), I couldn't get it to work.

I got around it by creating a new post with the information from the announcement, and deleting the old announcement.

This is probably what you did too.

Comment: Can confirm that this is a bug in the API and that the best workaround right now is to delete and re-create the post with the announcements.delete and announcements.create endpoints. You can keep track of the progress of the bug here: http://issuetracker.google.com/123653027